# Can Pixies wield shrunk two handed weapons?

Tags: dnd-4e, pixie

I was looking at building a ranger/artificer hybrid pixie, but the rules for weapon sizes seem to be contradicting. (Or maybe I'm just reading it wrong)

From page 28 of *Heroes of the Feywild*:

> **Wee Warrior:** You have a reach of 1, rather than the reach of 0 that is typical for a Tiny creature. You also take a -5 penalty to Strength checks to break or force open objects. When wielding a weapon of your size, you follow the same rules that Small creatures do.

From page 220 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> Small characters use the same weapons that Medium creatures do. However, a Small character (such as a halfling) can’t use a two-handed weapon. When a Small character uses a versatile weapon, he or she must wield it two-handed and doesn't deal any extra damage for doing so.

From page 28 of *Heroes of the Feywild*:

> **Shrink**
>   Pixie Racial Utility
>   *At your touch, an object shrinks to your wee size or is restored to its original state.*
>   **Encounter Minor Action ✦ Melee 1**
>   **Target:** One object that is sized for a Medium or Small creature, is not inside a container, does not contain anything, and is not held, worn, or carried by anyone other than you.
>   **Effect:** The target shrinks to a size appropriate for a Tiny creature's use. The new size ends at the end of your next extended rest unless the shrunken target is on your person. The size also ends if you or another pixie uses this power on the shrunken target. While shrunk, the target keeps its game statistics, such as damage dice and weight. A shrunken weapon, however, becomes an improvised one-handed weapon for a non-Tiny creature.

From page 220 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> One-Handed 1d4 ➛ 1d6 ➛ 1d8 ➛ 1d10 ➛ 1d12 ➛ 2d6 ➛ 2d8 ➛ 2d10
>   Two-Handed 1d8 ➛ 2d4 ➛ 1d10 ➛ 1d12 ➛ 2d6 ➛ 2d8 ➛ 2d10

Is a two handed weapon that has been shrunk "a size appropriate for a Tiny creature's use" Or can I not use it because "a Small character (such as a halfling) can’t use a two-handed weapon."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key phrases I'm seeing would lead me to believe that they can't use two-handed weapons.

You can shrink a Two-handed Weapon down to a *Tiny* size, although given the specific wording of *Shrink* I could quite possibly be wrong on that account, however it wouldn't be ***a size appropriate for a Tiny creature to use*** because you still have to ***follow the same rules that small creatures do when it comes to weapons*** and ***a Small character (such as a halfling) can’t use a two-handed weapon.***

The closest a tiny or Small creature can get to using a *Two-handed* Weapon is by using a weapon that has the *versatile* property because they have to use them with two hands but that doesn't increase it's damage die or give you the extra one damage that medium or larger creatures get.

Comment: It's important to note that Small races can use weapons with the Small property (which was introduced after the PHB1 rules cited above).  In particular, Pixies and other small characters wanting a 2 handed weapon should look at the Heavy War Pick, which is a +2 Proficiency 1d12 Military weapon with the High Crit and Small properties.  It's actually a pretty good weapon, but unfortunately as a Pick it doesn't get too much support from other quarters.